# What is the inclusion property between the Besov space $B^n_{\infty,1}(\mathbb{T})$ and $C^n(\mathbb T)$?

Tags: functional-analysis, fourier-analysis, harmonic-analysis

I am trying to understand the Besove space $B^n_{\infty, 1}(\mathbb T)$ on the unit circle. I also try to find some simple set inclusion of these subspaces with some known classical function space. I believe that $B^n_{\infty, 1}(\mathbb T)\subset C^{n}(\mathbb T)$ (n times continuously differentiable functions on unit circle $\mathbb T$),  but this is just my guess; I have no proof for this.

I request that you all provide proof or any reference where I can find this; it would be helpful.

Comment: See the bottom of the page at https://books.google.ca/books?id=Mb5DAAAAQBAJ&pg=PA130

Comment: Thank you for the information